# Which tool is best for drawing candle stick plot?

Tags: data, market-data, visualization

I'm considering to develop a visualization tool, in which the candle stick plot is a big part. I've seen people doing this using Python's matplotlib, Qt and PyQt. There are also several tools out there helping to draw financial plots. I'm now a bit lost, can anyone kindly give me some suggestions about which tool to use?
Other requirements: the plot needs to be dynamic, and can zoom in/out. Also, my programming skill is limited, C++ should be avoided in the case Python can solve the problem well enough.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/). It makes it very easy to create browser based dynamic visualizations from Python and integrates very well with Juptyer. [Here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html) is a candlestick example incl. pan, zoom, ...

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly the tool I need.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. Lately I found the [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com), which is in JavaScript.